# IF with INDEX & MATCH

Tags: excel, if-statement, match

I need to tell my formula to search for one specific value in two different tabs. I currently wrote this (and it's working):

> =INDEX(' table (2)'!I2:S727,MATCH('TEST'!P3&'TEST'!Q3,'table (2)'!G2:G727&'table (2)'!H2:H727,0),MATCH('TEST'!R3,'table
>   (2)'!I1:S1,0))

I have two conditions: BLUE and RED.

The above formula is searching for a specific value using BLUE as condition in table (2). I then added:

> =IF(N14="BLUE",INDEX(' table (2)'!I2:S727,MATCH('TEST'!P3&'TEST'!Q3,'table (2)'!G2:G727&'table
>   (2)'!H2:H727,0),MATCH('TEST'!R3,'table (2)'!I1:S1,0)))

Works fine.

I would like to make the formula knows that if I want the colour BLUE then search table (2), if I want red then search table (1).

My current spreadsheet has 3 tabs:

```
TEST = where my workings are
table (1) where RED data is
table (2) where BLUE data is
```

Comment: What software is this in? Excel? LibreOffice? Google Docs? What version? Is there any way you can create a small sample of the data, ideally a [mcve]?

Comment: @Mat How do you know this is Excel?

Comment: Just change the RED code in the IF statement (e.g. for when N14 is not blue) and change the references to reference your red table.

Comment: @IMSoP its excel 2016 - I ll try to provide data

Comment: @Timtech I’d like to have a formula that whenever N14 is blue or red, it would know which tab to pull the data from